# JS work with only one id and ignores other

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I ADDED TEXT RESIZER `<a href="#" id="small" class="selected">A</a>` BUT IT IS WORKING ON LAST ID , PLZ HELP ME TO FIX IT

```
<span class="category category--full">%s</span>
<h2 class="title title--full">%s</h2>
<div class="meta meta--full">
   <img class="meta__avatar" src="%s" alt="%s" />
   <span class="meta__author">%s</span>
   <span class="meta__date"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>%s</span>
   <span class="meta__reading-time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> %s</span>
   <span class="meta__misc meta__misc--seperator"></span>
   <span  class="meta__misc"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://hypnos.cosmicgirl.xyz?id=%s" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div></span><br><br><br>
   <nav class="article-nav">
       <button><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> <span>Previous</span></button>
       <button><span>Next</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
   </nav>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="controls">
    <a href="#" id="small" class="selected">A</a>
    <a href="#" id="medium" class="">A</a>
    <a href="#" id="large" class="">A</a>
  </div>
%s
</div>


     <p>lorem <a href="%s" target="_blank">link</a> by <span>%s</span> </p>
       <center><p> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://hypnos.cosmicgirl.xyz?id=%s" data-width="450" data-numposts="5"></div></p> </center> </article>',$myrow["title"],$myrow["titled"],$myrow["pic"],$myrow["title"],$myrow["author"],$myrow["date"],$myrow["time"],$myrow["id"],$myrow["text"],$myrow["link"],$myrow["author_d"],$myrow["id"]); }


                 ?>
```

HERE IS JS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#small").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"24px"});
    $("h2").animate({"font-size":"16px"});
    $("p").animate({"font-size":"12px", "line-height":"16px"});

  });

  $("#medium").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"36px"});
    $("h2").animate({"font-size":"24px"});
    $("p").animate({"font-size":"14px", "line-height":"20px"});

  });

  $("#large").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"48px"});
    $("h2").animate({"font-size":"35px"});
    $("p").animate({"font-size":"30px", "line-height":"40px"});

  });

  $( "a" ).click(function() {
   $("a").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");

 });

});
```

Comment: http://hypnos.cosmicgirl.xyz/ look, when i click resizer it is working only on last id

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a1dpqt

Comment: It is working here: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/u607b2bw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write is as following, this is more reliable code:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("a").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).addClass("selected");

     var type = $(this).attr('id');
     if(type=="small"){
         //Your code for small text
     }
     else if(type=="medium"){
         //Your code for medium text
     }
     else if(type=="large"){
         //Your code for large text
     }
});
```

Comment: HELLO, THANK YOU VERY MUCH, I AM STARTER IN JS ^_^ (Y)

Comment: SORRY I HAVE NOT ENOUGHT REPUTATION TO LIKE YOUR CODE